# R, Plotly, Layouts. Eliminación de annotations

Tags: r, layout, plotly

estoy tratando de hacer un subplot con dos graficos en plotly que tenían caption (en layouts, annotations=list(text)), pero no puedo sacarlos del subplot y me quedan en el medio de los graficos. A alguien se le ocurre como sacarlo?

Sobre los dos gráficos que ya tengo(g14So16 y g3E16) quiero compararlos en un solo grafico. Esto está pensado para una gran demanda de consultas, quizás lo más simple sea volver a escribir el código del gráfico sin la fuente, pero creo que debería poder eliminarse o modificarse el layout

Este es el codigo del plotly:

```
g14So16<- plot_ly(tabla1.3_GrSo2, x=reorder(tabla1.3_GrSo2$AGLOMERADO,-tabla1.3_GrSo2$Media)  ,y=~tabla1.3_GrSo2$Varones, type = 'bar', name = 'Varones', 
        marker = list(color ="#219C97")) %>% 
  add_trace(y = tabla1.3_GrSo2$Mujeres, name = 'Mujeres', marker = list(color = "#DFB021")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Aglomerado", tickangle = -70, size=0.7, colour = "#6F6F6E"),
         yaxis=  list(title = "Tasa subocupación",  size=0.7, colour = "#6F6F6E", range= c(0,20)),
         margin = list(b = 190, autosize=TRUE, autoexpand=TRUE),
         barmode = 'group', 
         title = list(x = 0.65, y = -0.65,
                text= "Tasas de subocupación según sexo, por aglomerado",
                size= 15,
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0),
         annotations = list(x = 0.75, y = -0.75, #position of text adjust as needed 
                text = 'Fuente: INDEC, Dirección de estadísticas sectoriales en base a a <a href=\"https://www.indec.gob.ar/uploads/informesdeprensa/indicadores_eph_3trim16.pdf" > informe EPH 3T 2016 </a>',  
                showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                font=list(size=10, color="#6F6F6E")),
          legend=list(x=100, y=0.5, title = list (text = '<b> Sexo </b>')))
```

Este es el codigo del subplot:

```
sp2<- g14So16 %>% layout( yaxis=list( range= c(0,80)), annotations=NULL) %>%
  subplot(style(g3E16,showlegend= TRUE, showannotations=FALSE), 
          nrows= 2,
          shareX=TRUE, shareY= TRUE, titleX = FALSE, titleY=FALSE,
          which_layout = 0)   %>% 
  layout( yaxis=list( range= c(0,80)),
          title= list(x = 0.75, y = -0.75,text= "Tasas de empleo y subocupación por aglomerado, Año 2016", size= 10,
          xshift=0, yshift=0),
          annotations=list(NULL)
         )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estimada Romina, bienvenida a stackoverflow. No me es posible reproducir tu código debido a que no cuento con las bases, pero te sugiero  eliminar las líneas de "text" en el código para que no salgan en la gráfica. Quedaría algo así:

```
g14So16<- plot_ly(tabla1.3_GrSo2, x=reorder(tabla1.3_GrSo2$AGLOMERADO,-tabla1.3_GrSo2$Media)  ,y=~tabla1.3_GrSo2$Varones, type = 'bar', name = 'Varones', 
        marker = list(color ="#219C97")) %>% 
  add_trace(y = tabla1.3_GrSo2$Mujeres, name = 'Mujeres', marker = list(color = "#DFB021")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Aglomerado", tickangle = -70, size=0.7, colour = "#6F6F6E"),
         yaxis=  list(title = "Tasa subocupación",  size=0.7, colour = "#6F6F6E", range= c(0,20)),
         margin = list(b = 190, autosize=TRUE, autoexpand=TRUE),
         barmode = 'group', 
         title = list(x = 0.65, y = -0.65,
                size= 15,
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0),
         annotations = list(x = 0.75, y = -0.75, #position of text adjust as needed  
                showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                font=list(size=10, color="#6F6F6E")),
          legend=list(x=100, y=0.5, title = list (text = '<b> Sexo </b>')))
```